# Which cities are connected by direct flights between Mexico and Asia?

Tags: air-travel, mexico, routes, southeast-asia, east-asia

Please include the airlines.

I'm only interested in **direct** flights. In particular no flight may be via USA.

Any country in East Asia and Southeast Asia is OK. I'll have a Chinese visa and can enter most other countries visa free or visa on arrival.

So far it seems that Aeromexico flies into Tokyo Japan, Shanghai China, and Seoul (Incheon) Korea. But I'm not even 100% positive these flights are direct.

Comment: Don't be afraid to tell us why you think it's off topic, silent drive by downvoter.

Comment: There might be a new option coming up: http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2018/02/03/hainan-airlines-mexico/

Answer (score 5):

I plugged "Mexico, anywhere" to "China, anywhere" for a random Friday in August into Skyscanner, and it only throws up one-stop connections - no direct flights. Ditto going to South Korea, India, Singapore. However, there *is* a  single direct flight from Mexico City to Tokyo (14h on Aeromexico).

On a Saturday, I can see a direct flight from Tijuana to Shanghai, as well as Mexico City to Tokyo again.

The flights are AM98 (to Shanghai) and AM58 (to Tokyo). The AM98 code is used for both Mexico City - Tijuana and Tijuana - Shanghai legs of the journey, but [looking at a recent flight map](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AMX98/history/20160713/0849Z/MMTJ/ZSPD) it seems pretty clear it's non-stop after Tijuana. AM58, likewise, [does not seem to stop](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AMX58/history/20160713/0650Z/MMMX/RJAA).

---

Going beyond that answer - if you're happy to tolerate a connection anywhere but the US, there are flights which connect in Canada; however, I think they have US-type transit visa requirements, so it might not be any more help. The long way around via a connection in Europe might be worth looking at in case a cheap ticket via some unusual route turns up; you can ([mostly](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)) have airside transit without visas there.

Comment: Yes Skyscanner doesn't seem any good at finding these but they do seem to exist. Inda is neither East nor Southeast Asia by the way. ANA airlines in japan had posted some news about direct flights to Mexico but I couldn't find details. The Shanghai-Tijuana seems to have very good prices at least showing up sometimes. I used to fly Australia-Japan-Canada-Mexico years ago but it works out a bit expensive.

Comment: @hippietrail good catch on India/SE Asia - I just saw "Asia" in the title and forgot the clarification in the text!

Comment: Here's a random link about the ANA flights: ["ANA plans direct flights to Mexico City from Narita"](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2016/01/29/business/corporate-business/ana-plans-direct-flights-mexico-city-narita/#.V4ihxrh94dU)

Comment: TIJ is starting to turn into an interesting airport for people traveling between Asia and the Americas who can't or don't want to transit the US...and for people who can, San Diego is a short walk away.

Comment: @MichaelHampton 5 years later its also a great airport if you want to fly to the US without getting a COVID test (no test for Mexico and no test for overland crossings to the US) :-)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.flightconnections.com/flights-from-mexico-city-mex lists the following direct flight from MEX airport to Asia:

- MEX -> ICN
- MEX -> IST (in Europe but a few kms away from Asia without having to cross a border)
- MEX -> NRT

[image]

https://www.flightconnections.com/flights-from-canc%C3%BAn-cun lists the following direct flight from CUN (Cancún) airport to countries that are partly in Asia (Russia and Turkey), but the airports themselves are in Europe:

- CUN -> IST
- CUN -> SVO Moscow Sheremetyevo
- CUN -> VKO Moscow Vnukovo (seasonal route that starts in December and ends in January)

[image]

---

https://www.flightconnections.com/flights-from-guadalajara-gdl, https://www.flightconnections.com/flights-from-monterrey-mty, https://www.flightconnections.com/flights-from-tijuana-tij shows no direct flights from GDL (Guadalajara), MTY (Monterrey) and TIJ airports to Asia.

---

MEX, CUN, GDL, TIJ and MTY are the [top 5 Mexican airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_busiest_airports_in_Mexico).

| # | Airport | IATA | ICAO | 2020<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_busiest_airports_in_Mexico#cite_note-sctstats-1)</sup> | % (19/20) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [Mexico City International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico_City_International_Airport) | MEX | MMMX | 21,977,268 | [image: Decrease]56.31% |
| 2 | [Cancún International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canc%C3%BAn_International_Airport) | CUN | MMUN | 12,259,148 | [image: Decrease]51.89% |
| 3 | [Guadalajara International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guadalajara_International_Airport) | GDL | MMGL | 8,094,115 | [image: Decrease]45.40% |
| 4 | [Tijuana International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tijuana_International_Airport) | TIJ | MMTJ | 6,310,798 | [image: Decrease]29.23% |
| 5 | [Monterrey International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monterrey_International_Airport) | MTY | MMMY | 4,994,170 | [image: Decrease]55.32% |
| 6 | [Los Cabos International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Cabos_International_Airport) | SJD | MMSD | 2,927,987 | [image: Decrease]45.16% |
| 7 | [Puerto Vallarta International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Vallarta_International_Airport) | PVR | MMPR | 2,489,825 | [image: Decrease]49.51% |
| 8 | [Del Bajío International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_Baj%C3%ADo_International_Airport) | BJX | MMLO | 1,377,573 | [image: Decrease]49.85% |
| 9 | [Culiacán International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culiac%C3%A1n_International_Airport) | CUL | MMCL | 1,373,102 | [image: Decrease]44.16% |
| 10 | [Mérida International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9rida_International_Airport) | MID | MMMD | 1,297,308 | [image: Decrease]53.51% |

Comment: `SVO` and `VKO` are not located in Asia, in fact it's strange that flightconnections is claiming that, it was pretty fine-grained with regards to world regions.

Comment: I've just re-checked and it does not claim so. *Please note that there are no direct services between Cancún and Africa, Southern Asia, China, Japan, Eastern Asia, South-Eastern Asia, Central Asia or Oceania* according to flightconnections.

Comment: @alamar thank you, good point, edited